# Como verificar se um valor está presente dentro de um array?

Tags: php, array

```
$idofdb = "25";

$myArray = array();
foreach ( $fthi as $codigo ) {
    $myArray[] = $codigo['ImoCodigo'];
}

$checkValues = array_values($myArray);
$checkString = implode(',', $checkValues); // 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,18,19,14,15,2
```

Eu gostaria de saber como comparar `$idofdb` com `$checkString` para saber se `$idofdb` está cadastrado no banco de dados. Como podemos observar,  a saída de `$checkString` é uma *string* de números separado por vírgulas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não precisa disto tudo, basta usa a função [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) direto no *array* original:

```
in_array("25", $fthi)
```

Ou se achar que deve fazer algo mais por algum motivo:

```
in_array("25", $checkValues)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/eSWvxf). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kpuoebfb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/Contains.php).

Answer (score 3):

Em vez de você transformar um array em uma string com números separados com vírgula você pode usar a função [in_array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php):

```
<?php

$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux"); 
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) { 
    echo "Tem Irix";
}
if (in_array("mac", $os)) { 
    echo "Tem mac";
}

?>
```

Olha o [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/z83e-vmt9) mostrando a execução.

Comment: Eu já li esse guia... php da para fazer aqui tb? Acho que ainda não né?

Comment: bom, você viu alguma referência a PHP lá? e quando pedimos "executar código" não acontece nada... então, não, não dá pra usar php... (vou apagar o comentário anterior e este pois já cumpriram sua função)

Answer (score 2):

Como os amigos disseram, não é necessário isso tudo. Mas se ainda sim você quiser verificar na *string*, você pode utilizar o [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php)

```
$pos = strpos($checkString, $idofdb);

if($pos == false) {
    echo 'Não tem cadastrado';
}else{
    echo 'A string foi encontrada na db';
}
```