# Verificar se um determinado valor existe dentro de um array

Tags: php

Colegas,

temos um menu com 11 itens e cada item abrirá uma página contendo seus respectivos arquivos em PDF. Para evitarmos criar 11 páginas diferentes, criamos apenas uma página chamada pdf.php e colocamos nos links desse menu da seguinte forma:

```
<a href='?pag=1'>Orçamentário</a>
<a href='?pag=2'>Dados</a>
<a href='?pag=3'>Contas</a>
```

Até o link número 11 e estamos resgatando dentro da mesma página que contém o menu dessa forma:

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['pag'])){ include("pdf.php?pag=".$_REQUEST['pag']);} ?>
```

Porém isso vai gerar uma querystring no navegador. Ex.: www.site.com.br?pag=1. Então para evitar que o usuário digite a numeração diretamente no navegador errada. Ex.: www.site.com.br?pag=12, gostaríamos que aparecesse uma mensagem para ele **Selecione um item do menu**.

Para evitar de dar um if() ou switch() 11 vezes, pensamos em criar um array com os valores fixos de 0 a 11 e caso não existisse esses valores, apareceria a mensagem.

Como poderíamos fazer isso? Pensamos em usar o in_array, mas não conseguimos. Veja:

```
$array = array("0","1","2","3");

if(in_array(array(), $array)){
    echo "ok";
}else{
    echo "ops";
}
```

Comment: Acho que a pergunta é dup

Comment: alem de ser suplicada voce esta passando o primeiro parametro errado o primeiro é o valor que que voce quer encontrar, nao um array vazio como usou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar de ser uma questão duplicada pelo conteúdo solicitado, o erro é específico da forma como está montando o seu `if`, que deveria ser da seguinte forma:

```
$array = array("0","1","2","3");

if(in_array($_GET['pag'], $array)){
    echo "ok";
}else{
    echo "ops";
}
```

Comment: Kenny, seria interessante antes de responder uma pergunta, verificar se a mesma já não é duplicata :)

Comment: acredito que fui bem claro na minha resposta com relação a isso...perguntas duplicadas podem ter soluções diferentes...

Comment: E no que difere? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100965/14262

Comment: Não é duplicada, pois o link que passaram é diferente da minha dúvida. A resposta do @KennyRafael funcionou dentro da minha necessidade.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio, difere que neste caso, ele já utilizava a solução correta porém da forma errada, diferente do seu exemplo em que a mesma foi apresentada a pessoa que perguntou...

Comment: nos links que me passaram, eu teria que usar condicionais e não é esse meu propósito.